# Is possible to check strongbox availability and bootloader relocking through adb?

Tags: android, adb, bootloader

I need to do some automatic checks, and I can't figure those despite some intense googling. Any ideas? Is possible to check strongbox availability and the possibility of bootloader relocking through adb?